# How do I get Excel language-ID via automation in C++?

Tags: c++, excel, com, localization

We have a C++ program that use automation/COM to communicate with Excel. We open files, export data and other operations. We use the wrapper classes generated for us in Visual Studio. (Wrappers to InvokeHelper calls.) Everything works fine.

Now I need to know which Excel language is installed on the user's machine. (Some of our users run Swedish Excel, some English Excel.) There is an interface for that: Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID().

But it seems this class is difficult to access via COM. There is a GetLanguageSettings() call in the _Application wrapper class, but there is no LanguageSettings class. We could of course do an InvokeHelper call ourselves, but I haven't found any dispid for the LanguageID call. And I haven't found any other way to access the language code for the installed Excel.

Any ideas? It seems strange if the LanguageSettings class/LanguageID call isn't available - they are easy to access from VB, for example. Is there any other way to get this information? We would be very grateful for any help! :-)

Comment: It is declared in a different type library, mso.dll.  Be sure to also write an #import directive for it.  The Office 2013 version is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE15\MSO.DLL

Comment: Ah - great, there is was! Thanks. :-) Couldn't find any documentation about that.